# Blank Screen Issue - KReporter

Tags: sugarcrm

I've installed KReporterBase_V_3_0_6 and KReporterCore_V_3_0_6 in Sugarcrm Professional Edition. When I try to create Report, it shows blank screen. Does anyone have the solution, please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a permissions issue. I had a similar issue earlier and got it solved by changing the file permissions. Check if the permissions are as mentioned in http://support.sugarcrm.com/04_Find_Answers/02KB/02Administration/100Install/Required_File_System_Permissions_on_Linux

Also disable Ajax for KReports through Admin->System Setting->Configure Ajax UI

Try and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

Blank screens in SugarCRM and other web applications usually indicate fatal PHP errors. Check your PHP log for recent messages. If there is nothing helpful in the PHP log, also check the SugarCRM log. It lives in the SugarCRM root directory, usually with a name like `sugarcrm.log`